# Client 2 Client File Encryption

Tags: c#, .net, file, encryption

I need some help with an exercise. We've been asked to create a simple software to simulate GDPR compliance for a fake company that handles patient data.

The exercise itself required us to create:

1. A secure database (done, Always Encrypted)
2. Secure communication (done, SSL & Reliable Sessions)
3. A way to store encrypted data on the server

Not sure how to best proceed with the third part. One client uploads a file, it should be stored encrypted on the server. A random second client downloads that file and it should be decrypted.

Our idea was to store the key in two sets. The client software holds one part of the key. The Service holds the second part. After a client has been authenticated it sends a query to say GetKey() when it needs to en/de-crypt a file, using a SerializableSecureString.
That string is then directly read into a SecureString on the client.

But I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. Or, if a better solution would be do Encrypt/Decrypt the files on the server, storing any keys in DPAPI.
The downside with that is, if an attacker gets hold of the server, by hacking rdp or something like tha,t it instantly gets hold of all files. 
If an attacker gets hold of a client machine, it will only get access to that users files and the files he/she can access.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You first have to define a threat. Without that, 'securing' something is meaningless.

Comment: The threat is someone gaining access to the server and getting hold of "patient data".

We first did a threat assessment, the clients and the server.

Hacking a client could potentially give a hacker access to a handful "patient data files".
Gaining access to the server would give a hacker access to potentially millions.

And that's why we asked if anyone knows of a good way to encrypt the fiels on the server, since the server doesn't need to know the file contect, but still making it possible for clients to decrypt.

Comment: Whan an attacker has control over your server, then how secure is that encrypted database ?

Comment: Securing the files like you describe requires a compicated key-sharing between clients... And that will likely fall apart when 1 client is compromised.

Comment: The database server (different machine), that has nothing to do with the file server, so slightly OT, is secured using windows accounts. The service can only read/write specified tables. The admin account, just like the db account, connects to the system using card readers. The database itself is encrypted using always encrypted. But sure, when someone gains direct access to it, they'd most likely get data of it. But not the files, since it's on a separate system.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: https://aws.amazon.com/kms or https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/

Services like these two allow you to have private key stored in a secure location (AWS, Azure).